# Sending GitHub notifications from different organizations to different addresses

Tags: email, notifications, github

I've got a GitHub account connected to two orgs. I regularly contribute to both, and also contribute independently to projects outside of either of these orgs.

Anytime I get a notification from any of these orgs, though, the emails about these notifications get sent to my primary, personal email.

For posterity and organization, I'd like to be able to do triage on these emails; for example, notifications on repositories belonging to `org A` should go to my email account with `org A`, notifications from `org B` should go to the `org B` email, with all other notifications going to my personal email.

Is there any way to do this? GitHub's email settings seem very minimal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible with help of [Custom routing](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-notification-emails-for-organizations/). First you'll have to add the relevant email address to your account.

To do this:

1. Head over to [Settings → Emails](https://github.com/settings/emails) and add & verify your email address
2. Now head over to [Settings → Notifications](https://github.com/settings/notifications)
3. Under Custom routing, choose the required email for the organization

[image]